# How do you nest jupyter widgets?

Tags: javascript, dom, widget, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a [custom Jupyter widget](https://github.com/aidan-plenert-macdonald/mxflows) (made from the [cookiecutter](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/widget-cookiecutter)) that would ideally have some custom javascript but then also make use of [existing widgets](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html) as well.

I can't find documentation on nesting widgets. How would I make a custom widget that has parts that are custom javascript, as well as using existing widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked too soon. You can use the Box widget (or VBox/HBox). See the [example code](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/master/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_box.py#L41) in the doc string.

Things like,

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
title_widget = widgets.HTML('<em>Box Example</em>')
slider = widgets.IntSlider()
box1 = widgets.Box([title_widget, slider])
widgets.VBox([box1, box1])
```

work fine. And if you look at the code in the class,

```
def __init__(self, children=(), **kwargs):
    kwargs['children'] = children
    super(Box, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.on_displayed(Box._fire_children_displayed)

def _fire_children_displayed(self):
    for child in self.children:
        child._handle_displayed()
```

You can see logic for managing children.